# Limit calculate using Maclaurin series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I need help to calculate this limit using Maclaurin series:
$\lim_{x\to \infty}((x^3-x^2+\frac{2}{x})e^{\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^3+x^6})$

I don't know from where to start. I think I need to to write Maclaurin series for
$e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and then use the remainder somehow... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

$$ e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{6x^3} + D_1$$

Comment: What should I do with D1? Can you elaborate more please, thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes. thanks!!!!